# Como capturar exceções lançadas pelo método insert()?

Tags: android, sqlite, exceção

Estou utilizando o SQLite para um banco local em uma aplicação Android, o meu problema é que não estou conseguindo tratar as exceções de restrição de integridade. Possuo uma tabela onde os dois campos são PK, ou seja, nunca poderá haver registros iguais. Quando tento inserir dois dados iguais ele lança a exceção:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting DIA=08-03-2018 HORA=02:06
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: 
UNIQUE constraint failed: TBPONTOSTEMP.DIA, TBPONTOSTEMP.HORA (code 1555)
```

Preciso tratar essa exceção para dar uma mensagem para o usuário, já utilizei tanto o Exception, como também o SQLiteException, SQLiteConstraintException. Segue o código:

```
public int cadastrarPontosTemp(String ponto, String dia){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    try{
        values.put("DIA",dia);
        values.put("HORA",ponto);
        getWritableDatabase().insert("TBPONTOSTEMP",null,values);
        Log.e("cadastrarPontosTemp","SUCESSO");

    }catch (SQLiteConstraintException e){
        Log.e("cadastrarPontosTemp",e.getMessage());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) captura qualquer SQLException lançada, tornando o seu bloco `try/catch` inútil no que se refere a excepções do tipo SQLException.

[Código fonte](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.insert%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.content.ContentValues%29) do método `insert()`:

```
public long insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {

    try {

        return insertWithOnConflict(table, nullColumnHack, values, CONFLICT_NONE);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Error inserting " + values, e);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

No entanto pode usar o valor retornado para verificar o sucesso da inserção. O valor retornado será o Id do novo registo ou -1 em caso de falha.

Se quer que uma excepção seja lançada use o método [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)).

[Código fonte](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.content.ContentValues%29) do método `insertOrThrow()`.

```
public long insertOrThrow(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {

    return insertWithOnConflict(table, nullColumnHack, values, CONFLICT_NONE);

}
```

Ambos chamam o método [insertWithOnConflict()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) para fazer o *insert*, passando o valor `CONFLICT_NONE` ao parâmetro `conflictAlgorithm`.

O valor passado a esse parâmetro serve para indicar qual o "algoritmo de conflito" a usar(ver [ON CONFLICT](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)).
`CONFLICT_NONE` indica que deve ser utilizado o "algoritmo de conflito" indicado na criação da tabela ou o padrão que é **ABORT**.

Use esse método quando pretender usar um "algoritmo de conflito" diferente.

Comment: Valeu, deu certo!